# Do requests in UIWebView use sharedHTTPCookieStorage?

Tags: iphone, cookies, uiwebview, httpwebrequest

From googling a bit, the answer to my question is "yes". But how do I test that?

I tried to inpsect the HTTP request headers (i.e. `[request allHTTPHeaderFields]`) in `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`, but none of the request has the "Cookie" entry, even though cookies are successfully stored in `[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this to loop through all the cookies in the UIWebView to verify they are there

```
NSHTTPCookie *aCookie;
for (aCookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) {
   NSLog(@"%@", aCookie);
}
```

Comment: Yes, the cookies are there. I just printed out the array: `NSLog(@"%@", [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies])`